# Parse xml using XmlSlurper in Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, xml-parsing, xmlslurper

I have an xml response which looks like :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <multiRef xmlns:ns9="http://hero.ar.vixo.in" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" id="id2" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns9:IdentityModel">
         <vixId xsi:type="xsd:int">13364719</vixId>
      </multiRef>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This response is stored in a `String` name `xmlMsg`
I am trying to parse it as follows:-

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlMsg);
def vixId = xml.Body.multiRef.vixId.text()
```

But the problem here is that before reading `vixId` i want to verify if 'type' in `multiRef` tag is `IdentityModel`

I tried accessing `type` as follows, but in vain :-

```
def vixId = xml.Body.multiRef.@type.text()
```

Please note that i am able to access `id` in `multiRef` tag using as follows:-

```
 def vixId = xml.Body.multiRef.@id.text()
```

Please help me in accessing `type` in `multiRef` tag

EDIT:
Please note that i want to parse the `type` in `multiRef` tag without using name space like `multiRef.'@xsi:type'` because my `namespace` could change. All i want is that `multiRef` tag has a attribute `type` and that has a value of `IdentityModel`.. Only if this is there then I want to read `vixId`.
Also note that with groovy 1.8 i was parsing it without namespace using `multiRef.@type` but it has stopped working ever since i updated groovy to 2.4.7

PS:- I am fairly new in dealing with xmls

Comment: `xml.Body.multiRef.'xsi:@type'.text()` ?

Comment: @har07 : nopes, but  `xml.Body.multiRef.'@xsi:type'.text()` returned  `ns9:IdentityModel` .... Thanks for your help  , it will be great if theres any way to get only `IdentityModel` as response... if now, i will use string manipulations to achieve it :D .. thanks

Comment: ah, typo. That's what I meant

Answer (score 1):

By default XMLSlurper is not namespace aware. This can be turned on by declaring namespaces with the declareNamespace Method.

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlMsg)
             .declareNamespace('xsi' : 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance')
def vixId = xml.Body.multiRef.vixId.text()
println vixId

def type = xml.Body.multiRef.@'xsi:type'.text()
println type
```

The output is:

```
13364719
ns9:IdentityModel
```

This returns the string value `ns9:IdentityModel` which is the exact value in the XML. If want to strip the namespace prefix, can do something like `type = type.replace('ns9:','')` to end up with "IdentityModel".

Comment: Thanks for your response, but when i was using earlier version of groovy(1.8), i had acheived it using :- `def xml = new XmlSlurper(FactorySupport.createSaxParserFactory().newSAXParser().GETXMLReader()).parseText(xmlMsg)` and then using `xml.Body.multiRef.@type` ..... and now i have upgraded to groovy 2.4.7 and in that i am not able to access `IdentityModel` directly using `@type`.... can u suggest any way so that only usin `@type` will work

Comment: Please note that it is working if i do it as @har07 has suggested `xml.Body.multiRef.'xsi:@type'.text()` without using the `declareNameSpace ` method

Answer (score 0):

Did not exactly find what i was looking for yet, but i have used a temporary workaround for the time being :-

```
    if (xml.Body.multiRef.attributes().toString().contains("IdentityModel")) {
        vixId = xml.Body.multiRef.vixId.text()
    }
```

Here `attributes()` method will give an array of all the attributes, their namespaces and values